# Filling the Goal of FollowJointTrajectory in Python

Tags: python, smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm using Python to create (for my ros_smach) a connection to the ActionServer "control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectory". To call the function SimpleActionState() I have to specify a goal. I hard-coded this goal1 and tried to pass it through the function call.

```
        # Define the goal for the ActionServer
        goal1=FollowJointTrajectoryGoal()  #create an empty goal    
        goal1.trajectory.points[0].positions = [296.82, 294.143, 523.638, -46.3056, 71.3728, -137.832]  #define the point position of the goal(hard-coded) !!!This line gives an error saying "IndexError: list index out of range"!!!

        # Add a state to the container
        smach.StateMachine.add('PTP1',
            smach_ros.SimpleActionState('SiliaAction_TrajServer', 
                                         FollowJointTrajectoryAction, 
                                         goal = goal1
                                       ),
            transitions={'succeeded':'NextState'})
```

The problem is this created goal1 does not have an entry called "positions" under goal1.trajectory.points. To be more precise, goal1.trajectory.points is an empty array, which looks like this if I print it out:

```
trajectory: 
  header: 
    seq: 0
    stamp: 
      secs: 0
      nsecs: 0
    frame_id: ''
  joint_names: []
  points: []  # here it is
path_tolerance: []
goal_tolerance: []
goal_time_tolerance: 
  secs: 0
  nsecs: 0
```

Is there any method to fill in this goal and pass it on, for example by the time when calling the constructor FollowJointTrajectoryGoal() and fill my desired positions here?

Thank you for your answers!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54319/filling-the-goal-of-followjointtrajectory-in-python/) by [Mingyuan Wang](https://answers.ros.org/users/4136/mingyuan-wang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-02-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should look at the index error. You can't access `points[0]` as it doesn't exist yet. The list is empty. Use `points.append(...)` to add an entry to the list.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1